# Can't run selenium driver on ec2

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, celery

I collect reviews through a parser that uses chromedriver , I run parsing in a celery task on the server, i faced the following error

```
  (The process started from chrome location /home/ubuntu/.../chromedriver 
is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

this is the path returned by the ChromeDriverManager.

Do I need to somehow install and configure the Google browser on the server?
Here my chrome options:

```
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Adding argument to disable the AutomationControlled flag
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        # Exclude the collection of enable-automation switches
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,800")

        # Turn-off userAutomationExtension
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
        path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
        chrome_options.binary_location = path #"/home/ubuntu/chromedriver"
        service = Service(path)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone will faced the same issue try to download chromium-browser and change binary_path=/usr/bin/chromium-browser , keep in mind that u have to setup the same versions.